# Summation Simplication

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{y\,:\,y=x} P(x,y) = P(x,x)$$

How did the summation get removed? I expected it to simplify into

$$\sum_{y\,:\,y=x} P(x,x)$$

or

$$\sum_{all \, x} P(x,x)$$

Comment: Given $x$, how many $y$ exists so that $y=x$?

Comment: Oh there's only 1, when y = x.

Comment: Yes! So the first one of your expected sums equates to $P(x,x)$, which is correct. The second sum you have written up is simply incorrect.

Comment: Does $P(x, x)$ equals $P(x)$? Since $x \cap x = x$ or are the "x"s different like $x_1, x_2$?